# Android 6 - phone crashes when bluetooth device found

Tags: android, bluetooth, crash

I'm currently in the process of developping an Android app and everything worked fine before I updated my phone's Android to CyanogenMod 13 for Oneplus One. Now my system crashes shortly before my app was supposed to receive the `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND` Intent.
Permissions requested in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I'm requesting location permissions on runtime as well!
Start Discovery:

```
registerReceiver(discoveredDevice, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
btAdapter.startDiscovery()
```

Then after some time using Android Monitor targetting `com.android.bluetooth` I can see the following: (hope I coppied all that's important) (The device I'd like to receive is that HTC Wildfire, just in case you're wondering)

```
06-04 19:04:15.961 30465-30582/com.android.bluetooth D/bt_osi_alarm: reschedule_root_alarm alarm expiration too close for posix timers, switching to guns
06-04 19:04:17.242 30465-30477/com.android.bluetooth I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15038(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 275(5MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 15MB/25MB, paused 5.926ms total 27.652ms
06-04 19:04:17.641 30465-30586/com.android.bluetooth W/bt_btm: btm_process_inq_results: BDA: 90-21-55-9a-58-65
06-04 19:04:17.641 30465-30586/com.android.bluetooth W/bt_btm: btm_process_inq_results: Dev class: 5a-02-0c
06-04 19:04:17.645 30465-30575/com.android.bluetooth D/BluetoothRemoteDevices: Remote Address is:90:21:55:9A:58:65
06-04 19:04:17.645 30465-30575/com.android.bluetooth D/BluetoothRemoteDevices: Remote Device name is: HTC Wildfire
06-04 19:04:17.646 30465-30575/com.android.bluetooth D/BluetoothRemoteDevices: Remote class is:5898764
06-04 19:04:17.646 30465-30575/com.android.bluetooth D/BluetoothRemoteDevices: deviceFoundCallback: Remote Address is:90:21:55:9A:58:65
06-04 19:04:20.197 30465-30465/com.android.bluetooth D/HeadsetPhoneState: sendDeviceStateChanged. mService=1 mSignal=3 mRoam=0 mBatteryCharge=5
06-04 19:04:20.197 30465-30597/com.android.bluetooth D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 11, size: 0
06-04 19:05:52.680 30465-30485/com.android.bluetooth D/BtGatt.GattService: Binder is dead - unregistering client (5)!
06-04 19:05:52.681 30465-30485/com.android.bluetooth W/BinderNative: Uncaught exception from death notification
                                                                     java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission: Neither user 1002 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN.
                                                                         at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1450)
                                                                         at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1482)
                                                                         at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:681)
                                                                         at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.enforceAdminPermission(GattService.java:2148)
                                                                         at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.stopMultiAdvertising(GattService.java:1500)
                                                                         at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$ClientDeathRecipient.binderDied(GattService.java:255)
                                                                         at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:558)
```

Mind the time that that error is being thrown (about one and a half minutes later)!
During that time the phone is frozen, which means I can't do anything than turning screen off (not even on again is possible) or rebooting. If I wait that long the phone reboots itself!

Now my question is whether this problem is my fault or CyanogenMod's.
Thanks for any help!

---

**See solution below that poses another question!**

Comment: do androids have dmesg logs?

Comment: What exactly am I supposed to look for in dmesg log?

Comment: something relating to bluetooth

Comment: I am not able to find anything, however I uploaded two logs: During hung up state (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9yy3TGLUYoNUmppSHZyX1h2MVk) and at reboot (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9yy3TGLUYoNc2dNejNzanpIU1U)

Comment: I finally managed to test the above on my brother's OnePlus One (unlike me he's still on Cyanogen OS) and it worked like a charm! Therefore I'm assuming either the CyanogenMod version is broken or something went wrong during installation process. I'm now going to reinstall CyanogenMod and report back!

Answer (score 1):

*Well that was stressful....
As mentioned in the comments above, I tried my app using my brother's OnePlus One on Stock Cyanogen OS and it worked. Then I reinstalled my CyanogenMod and... Problem still unsolved, which made me think the OS' version must be corrupted, however on the Cyanogen bugtracker noone else had that issue. Because of that i decided I would wipe my phone completely (including all data and everything!) and reinstall CyanogenMod again. Confusingly enough now everything works fine!
(Still I'm scratching my head whether it can be true that during two installation procedures the same corruption occurs or it was something else that caused that problem??)*   ------- **This is not the answer!**

---

This actually didn't solve my problem as I noticed when tying again later. After a few reinstalls I finally figured out that **Cyanogen's Privacy Guard** caused the problem! Disabling it for my app solves it! Does anyone know why Privacy Guard does this and what I can do about it?

Comment: Had a similar problem with bluetooth scan making the Oneplus One crash. Settings > Confidentiality > "Data protection", and disable the application

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it when I disabled location accuracy using bluetooth. Improving location accuracy using bluetooth freezes the phone when it can't determine your location. Hope this helps. Thanks.